# Problem with getting bandwidth information from mininet

Tags: postman, sdn, mininet, opendaylight

I am trying to get the information for link's bandwidth from `mininet` by using `Opendaylight` Controller, but the problem is that even though there are different links with different bandwidth in the `mininet` topology, the information that I get from `opendaylight` controller (using Postman) is showing the same result for every link.

The python code used to create the topology is:

```py
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import CPULimitedHost
from mininet.link import TCLink
from mininet.util import dumpNodeConnections
from mininet.log import setLogLevel
from mininet.topo import Topo

class MyTopo( Topo ):
    "Simple topology example."

    def __init__( self ):
        "Create custom topo."

        # Initialize topology
        Topo.__init__( self )

        # Add hosts and switches
        H1 = self.addHost( 'h1' )
        H2 = self.addHost( 'h2' )
        H3 = self.addHost( 'h3' )
        H4 = self.addHost( 'h4' )

        S1 = self.addSwitch( 's1')
        S2 = self.addSwitch( 's2')
        S3 = self.addSwitch( 's3')
        S4 = self.addSwitch( 's4')

        # Add links
        self.addLink( H1, S1,cls = TCLink, bw = 5)
        self.addLink( H2, S2,cls = TCLink, bw = 1)
        self.addLink( H3, S3,cls = TCLink, bw = 1)
        self.addLink( H4, S4,cls = TCLink, bw = 1)
        self.addLink( S1, S2,cls = TCLink, bw = 1)
        self.addLink( S2, S3,cls = TCLink, bw = 1)
        self.addLink( S3, S4,cls = TCLink, bw = 1)
        self.addLink( S4, S1,cls = TCLink, bw = 1)

topos = { 'mytopo': ( lambda: MyTopo() ) }
```

The result from opendaylight controller is:

- [Info for Link S1-S2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOh9w.png)
- [Info for Link S2-S3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbVU3.png)

The result for  "sh ovs-ofctl -O OpenFlow13 dump-ports-desc s1", where s1-eth1 is the port that connects H1 with S1:

[image: S1-info]

I would really appreciate if someone could help me find a way to get the real information for link capacities from mininet.

Answer (score 1):

you can try the following command from within mininet CLI:
sh ovs-ofctl -O openflow13 dump-ports-desc s1

Comment: Thank you! I have already tried it and it is giving the same result as Postman.

Comment: Please check again, I have updated the question with the photo of the results that you asked for!

Comment: based the mininet log during the net building, I can say that the links BW matches your code, anyway, try iperf between H1 and H3 then between H2 and H3 and figure out the difference

Answer (score 0):

Here is mine demo conf. for mininet router.py

```
class LinuxRouter(Node): 

def config(self, **params):
    super(LinuxRouter, self).config(**params)
    self.cmd('sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1') 

def terminate(self):
    self.cmd('sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=0') 
    super(LinuxRouter, self).terminate()


class NetworkTopo(Topo): 

def build(self, **_opts):

    router = self.addNode('r0', cls=LinuxRouter, ip='192.168.1.1/24')

    h1_01 = self.addHost('h1_01', ip='192.168.1.100/24', defaultRoute='via 192.168.1.1')
    h1_02 = self.addHost('h1_02', ip='192.168.1.150/24', defaultRoute='via 192.168.1.1')

    h2_01 = self.addHost('h2_01', ip='172.16.0.100/12', defaultRoute='via 172.16.0.1')
    h2_02 = self.addHost('h2_02', ip='172.16.0.150/12', defaultRoute='via 172.16.0.1')

    h3_01 = self.addHost('h3_01', ip='10.0.0.100/8', defaultRoute='via 10.0.0.1') 
    h3_02 = self.addHost('h3_02', ip='10.0.0.150/8', defaultRoute='via 10.0.0.1') 
    h3_03 = self.addHost('h3_03', ip='10.0.0.200/8', defaultRoute='via 10.0.0.1') 

    s1 = self.addSwitch('s1') 
    s2 = self.addSwitch('s2') 
    s3 = self.addSwitch('s3') 

    self.addLink(h1_01, s1) 
    self.addLink(h1_02, s1) 
    self.addLink(h2_01, s2) 
    self.addLink(h2_02, s2) 
    self.addLink(h3_01, s3) 
    self.addLink(h3_02, s3) 
    self.addLink(h3_03, s3) 

    self.addLink(s1, router, intfName2='r0-eth1', params2={'ip': '192.168.1.1/24'}) 
    self.addLink(s2, router, intfName2='r0-eth2', params2={'ip': '172.16.0.1/12'}) 
    self.addLink(s3, router, intfName2='r0-eth3', params2={'ip': '10.0.0.1/8'}) 


def run():
    topo = NetworkTopo() 
    net = Mininet(topo=topo) 
    net.start() (

    print net['r0'].cmd('route') 
    CLI(net) 
    net.stop() 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    setLogLevel('info')
    run()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yg770.png)